# Working with large text files

Tags: c++

I am trying to import a map, stored as .txt file, with 99 million nodes. I have tried to store these nodes in an array or in a vector, but unfortunately I am facing the limits of both. 
I have looked in the possibility to mmap the file, but can't seem to get it working.

Can anyone give an advice?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: why does mmap not work?  There are several [examples](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) -- what does you code look like?

Comment: Why don't share them partially between several arrays or vectors? It sounds better.\

Comment: What is size of node  ? How do you want to access the data ?

Comment: Paolo, when trying to declare an array with 99 million components I get the error "error C2148: total size of array must not exceed 0x7fffffff bytes"

Comment: by fstat or stat you can find the size of file, then you can dynamically allocate for that size.

Comment: You should not allocate large arrays at compile time (ie not writing `Type array[LARGE_NUMBER]`. Besides it's likely that the number of neded elements are not known at compile time anyway. Use `new` and `delete` instead.

Comment: Will you need to parse the nodes before you process the data?

Comment: When memory mapping on some systems you should not allocate the space manually as the system does that during memory mapping (how it's done differ depending on OS), then you'll need placement `new` instead.

Comment: map does one single allocation per node, and you probably fragment the memory too much. We would need also to know how big is the file and how big is each node.

Comment: I do have 99 miilion nodes. Each node has an ID, latitude and longitude. These are currently stored in a text file. The job is to add waypoints (connections to other nodes) to these individual nodes in order to create a useable navigation map. Therefore I will have to parse the nodes in a 3D array or vector in order to be able to add the additional infor